# How do I remove elements of an array without using methods or functions

Tags: java

I need to get the union of two sets without repeated or duplicate elements. I'm not allowed to use methods and functions. Need to code from scratch.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class MyClass {

public static void main (String[] args) {

    int setA[] = {1,3,5,7,10,11};
    int setB[] = {2,4,7,12,15};
    
    MyClass set=new MyClass();
    set.union(setA, setB);
public void union(int setA[],int setB[]) {
    String hold="";
    for(int i=0;i<setA.length;i++) {
        hold+=setA[i]+" ";
}
    for(int i=0;i<setB.length;i++) {
        hold+=setB[i]+" ";
}
    System.out.println(hold);
}
```

The output is:

```
1 3 5 7 10 11 2 4 7 12 15
```

Comment: You are using `set.union` function already.

Comment: The union of two integer set should result in an integer set.  First, dump the content of setA into a tmp array of size (setA length + setB length).   Then add only values in setB to tmp if it's not already in temp.  Keep track of how many numbers have been added to tmp.  Create a new array unionAB of size of the number of values added to tmp.  Copy the values in tmp to unionAB.

Answer (score 0):

Probably can be done easier. What I do here is:

1. Create array that can fit both arrays if nothing is duplicated
2. Copy `resA` to resulting array
3. For every element `b` check if it is not there yes in `res`
4. If element is there already - skip the iteration, if it is not, add and it
5. As a cleanup, trim down the array to the length of actual elements which are not 0

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   ```
   int setA[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 11};
   int setB[] = {2, 4, 7, 12, 15};
   int[] res = new int[setA.length + setB.length];
   //copy a to res
   int pointer = 0;
   for (; pointer < setA.length; pointer++) {
       res[pointer] = setA[pointer];
   }
   for (int b : setB) {
       boolean alreadyThere = false;
       for (int i=0;i<pointer;i++) {
           if (res[i] == b) {
               alreadyThere = true;
               break;
           }
       }
       if (alreadyThere) continue;
       res[pointer++] = b;
   }

   //optionally shrink down to pointer length
   int ret[] = new int[pointer];
   for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++) {
       ret[i] = res[i];
   }

   //print out
   Arrays.stream(ret).forEach(r -> System.out.print(r + " "));
   ```

   }

As a curiosity, it is possible to do it without boolean flag by using labels (which is discouraged nowdays)

```
for (int b : setB) skipIt:{
    for (int i=0;i<pointer;i++) {
        if (res[i] == b) {
            break skipIt;
        }
    }
    res[pointer++] = b;
}
```

Output

```
1 3 5 7 10 11 2 4 12 15
```